# Changing a information during a tween

Tags: actionscript-3, tween, gsap

I want to change a movieclip.text during a tween.

I got this function, can I change the information on this movieclip when this Tween is happening?

```
function facaTween(m:MovieClip){
   TweenLite.to(m,1,{rotationX:360,ease:Strong.easeInOut}); 
   }
```

when I tryed this code the as3 changes the information before the tween happens and i want during the tween.

```
facaTween(hue.obs);
hue.obs.text = "HAHAH";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update text in any time, when you want, TweenLite is powerful:

- *onComplete* - change text after tween complete
- *onStart* - change text at start, right before start

Example:

```
TweenLite.to(m,1,{rotationX:360, onComplete:onFinish, onStart: onBegin, ease:Strong.easeInOut});

function onFinish():void{
    hue.obs.text ="Complete";
}
function onBegin():void{
    hue.obs.text = "Start";
}
```

During, you mean with small delay? You can change text a bit after you start tween:

```
TweenLite.delayedCall(0.2, onSmallDelay);

function onSmallDelay():void{
    hue.obs.text = "text after 200ms";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I used the delayedCall and it works perfectly